# How to select random divs in a banner rotation

Tags: javascript, banner

I have managed to create a banner rotation for my website but it rotates 1,2,3,1,2,3.. and so on. I have done some research but cannot seem to find a specific solution to my problem.

The problem is that I would like them to rotate randomly so that the first banner listed is not always the first one that appears because we cannot favour one client over another.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function() {
    startRotator("#rotator");
  })
</script>

<div id="rotator">

<div>
<a href="http://www.website.com" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Middle Banner', 'Banner_Click', 'Middle Banner 1 November 2017');" target="_blank">
<img class="mid-banner" src="/images/banners/middle/banner1.jpg" />
</a>
</div> 

<div> 
<a href="http://www.website.net" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Middle Banner', 'Banner_Click', 'Middle Banner 2 November 2017');" target="_blank">
<img class="mid-banner" src="/images/banners/middle/banner2.jpg" />
</a>
</div>

<div>
<a href="http://www.website.co.uk" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Middle Banner', 'Banner_Click', 'Middle Banner 3 November 2017');" target="_blank">
<img class="mid-banner" src="/images/banners/middle/banner3.jpg" />
</a>
</div>

</div>

<script>
function rotateBanners(elem) {
var active = $(elem+" div.active");
var next = active.next();
if (next.length == 0) 
next = $(elem+" div:first");
active.removeClass("active").fadeOut(200);
next.addClass("active").fadeIn(200);
}

function prepareRotator(elem) {
$(elem+" div").fadeOut(0);
$(elem+" div:first").fadeIn(0).addClass("active");
}

function startRotator(elem) {
prepareRotator(elem);
setInterval("rotateBanners('"+elem+"')", 7000);

}
</script>
```

Is there any way that I can make them appear in a random order such as 3,1,2,1,3,2... and so on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: 1: Generate a random number - `random()`.
2: Put that random value into `eq()` and use that to select a slide at random.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways.  Here's what I would do.

First, to make it clear, I would give the slide `div`s a class:

```
<div class="slide">
```

Then in JS:

```
// Select all slides
var slides = $('div.slide');
// Pick the index of one to show at random (well, pseudo-random)
var showIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (slides.length - 1));
// Fade out the active slide
$('.active', slides).fadeOut(200);
// Get the slide to show by its index and fade it in
slides.eq(showIndex).fadeIn(200);
```

You could also make it a little better by checking if the currently active slide is at the same index as the random number and pick another random number:

```
var showIndex = -1;
while (showIndex != slides.index('.active')) {
    showIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (slides.length - 1));
}
```

Comment: Hello Matt,

Thank you for answering my question - unfortunately I still cannot seem to get this to work. I am very new to this so I may be doing something wrong. Please could you clarify where I would need to put each piece of code. 

I have spent all morning trying about 1000 different ways but none seem to work correctly for me.

Thanks again for the help!

Dave